# Joomla 3.3.3| How to Add Style Class to tinymce editor

Tags: joomla3.0

Joomla 3.3.3, I can't manage to find the "style add button" to set custom styles from the editor

- image of tinyMCE in older JOOMLA version, [Image](http://i58.tinypic.com/2uyotpx.png)

**i am looking for the red marked dropdown**

- image of tinyMCE in JOOMLA 3.3.3 , [Image](http://i60.tinypic.com/mczz34.png)

Comment: would you like to rephrase your post into a question? i don't quite understand what you are asking

Comment: @Banana, What I want to achieve is- set a custom CSS class in the "template_name"\templates\system\css\editor.css and then see it in the Style drop down (for letting my customers choose & see the class style in tinyMCE editor. Clear now?

Comment: usually a question is followed by a question mark, "i cant ..." is not a question. but yes, its clear now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable extended functionality to TinyMCE editor plugin at:

```
Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> Editor - TinyMCE -> Functionality: Extended
```

For extra format addition you have to check [online format editor](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php) tutorial.

In order to implement them to joomla you have to copy `style_formats` in the file: `/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php`

[image]

* please note that it is a core file change that joomla update may override (you have to keep a backup of your updated file). You may try to make a template override but I don't think that would be easy.

Hope this helps

Comment: I already have Extended enabled. What I want to achieve is- set a custom CSS class in the "template_name"\templates\system\css\editor.css and then see it in the Style drop down (for letting my customers choose & see the class style in tinyMCE editor.

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for, but I am having trouble to understand how to implement it. I have looked for "style_formats" in the "tinymce.php" file, there no such. so where should I insert it? can you show me some guide?

Comment: Sure, if you are using extended view you have to put the whole style_formats block at line 718.

Comment: I tried with this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQ-igrucATg   , it's changed since then ?

Comment: Please try my suggestion, copy style_formats: [ ... ] and paste them to line 718 in tinymce.php.

Answer (score 3):

*I wouldn´t not modify core Joomla files (like the tinymce.php) as with every update you need to change that as well. Here is how it is done out of the box:*

1. Login into the backend from your Joomla installation
2. Go to Extensions -> Plugins and search for TinyMCE once found edit the plugin
3. Inside the TinyMCE option you can find a setting called "Template CSS Classes". Keep noted that you can have different TinyMCE sets here, so you need to perform the following for the correct set!
4. Make sure the "Template CSS Classes" is set on yes. If that is the case, the Plugin looks for an editor.css file in the default template, if it cannot find one it will load the editor.css file in system template.
5. Now copy the file /templates/system/css/editor.css to /templates//css/editor.css
6. Now you can add custom styled to the editor.css in your template folder which you can then choose in Joomla.

[image]

An working example could be found [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/joomla/427-howto-add-own-formats-to-the-tinymce-editor-in-joomla.html).